# How to access modem inside Android mobile from a PC through USB cable?

Tags: integrated-circuit, microchip, cellphone, android, modem

Every mobile has a modem inside it, which allows dialing phone numbers and connecting to data/GPRS.
I guess we can send AT commands to all modems in phones.
So if I tear down an Android phone e.g. a Samsung Galaxy M31, how do I interface the modem to a PC via USB?

e.g. iPhone 12:

[image: iphone 12 modem]

Comment: Why do you guess it's possible? It might be impossible to access it via USB, for example if it has PCIe interface. What problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: e.g. iPhone 12 or Samsung Galaxy M31.  What has iPhone have to do with Android?

Comment: iphone and samsung both have modem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely not possible on all phones, and probably not possible on the vast majority of them. Even if the at command interface wasn't disabled and was unauthenticated (unlikely), theres a very high chance that the interface is not USB (as Justme mentions) - it could be UART, pcie, or any other protocol.